# Microchip's pic-as throws syntax error on macro define

Tags: microchip, assembly, error, macro

I have a file with a name like `xxxx.asm`

in it I have:

`InitPORTA  MACRO`

pic-as throws a syntax error on this line.
The code compiled fine with:
`mpasmx -rdec pic-code.s`
I thought `*.asm` files were the file type that pic-as took to mean assembly with no C contructs in them and would thus assemble them as the older assembler did.
Is there something obvious I missed?

Comment: for pic-as you nedd `*.s` files and not `*.asm` files.

Comment: Also consider what file encoding is being used on the source file. Could be that the assembler is expecting a different type.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in pic-as
InitPortA(space)(space)---(space)MACRO
made the syntax error happen.  Replacing the white spaces with a press of the tab key made that line compile.  It seems that not all white spaces are taken as the same thing
This has become moot for me because I rolled back to v5.35 and mpasmx. I think it is better to finish my project with that version.  I saw reports on line that suggested that pic-as is quite buggy.  Perhaps my issue was one of the bugs.

Comment: What _exactly_ is '(space)(space)---(space)'? Please show your actual source code text, using the 'code sample' tag.

Comment: At about line 3 of my initial question is a copy-and-paste of the line of text from the source file.  My '(space)(space)---(space)' represents some number of presses of the space bar that I don't know.  I didn't keep the original so how many it was would be an estimate.  The word "MACRO" was aligned at column 16 so 7 would be the number of spaces.

Comment: Maybe edit your answer with the <code sample tag>

Answer (score 1):

`MPASM` and `pic-as` are using different file types:
MPASM: `*.asm` files
pic-as: `*.s` files

Please remember, there are a lot more differences between these assembler types. See this [document](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPASM%20to%20MPLAB%20XC8%20PIC%20Assembler%20Migration%20Guide%2050002973A.pdf) for the details.